# how to get Libre Office Calc to tell me when there are invalid characters

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet in XLSX format that was generated by a python program.  it turns out that the python program had left some invalid characters in the file.  When I open the file in Excel, it at least tells me that there is a problem.  Libre Office Calc just opens the file and silently tries to correct the problem, leaving lots of blank cells.

Is there a way to tell Calc to warn me if there is a problem opening the file?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not answering the question directly, but IMHO a better approach would be to validate the XLSX files just after generation.

There are different offline and online validators available for both OOXML and ODF documents. To single out just two sites:

- At [document-interoperability.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20110901001836/http://www.document-interoperability.com:80/), there's an [overview of what's available at the moment](http://www.document-interoperability.com/web/guest/validation), together with an [online validator for OOXML files](http://www.document-interoperability.com/validator).
- MS offers the "[Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk)" include validation tools; here's a [related blog post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericwhite/validate-open-xml-documents-using-the-open-xml-sdk-2-0).